# Stripe TLS 1.2 Upgrade Issues

Tags: php, ssl, stripe-payments, tls1.2

My website is running TLS 1.2, as verified by https://www.ssllabs.com/
However, I keep seeing in Stripe that charges are coming through as TLS 1.0, and that I need to upgrade.

I called Hostmonster, and they also verified I am on TLS 1.2.

So what am I missing? Why are the charges still coming through TLS 1.0??

I am using Stripe with PHP.

Comment: i get emails from multiple payment gateways about changes, they simply may not apply to you - are you sure they are saying that YOU have to change something?

Comment: You are not clear. "charges are coming through as TLS 1.0" what does that mean? Your server is contacted at some URL? Note that it is still very rare today to see servers being TLS 1.2 only. They are often TLS 1.0 or 1.1 or 1.2, trying the highest version possible but it is a negotiation between server and client. You do not give enough useful information, URL concerned by the problem, etc.

Comment: "Stripe with PHP" is very vague. Are you using the official Stripe SDK? Did you write custom code to connect to Stripe? In the end, the key is which HTTP library (curl, zend-http, etc.), and ultimately the underlying lib for encryption (probably OpenSSL) . It might help if you post your OS and version which will help determine your general environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is not with your certificate (as tested by SSLLabs), but with the TLS communication between your server and your gateway (Stripe in this case). Payment providers are removing support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 due to some changes in PCI compliance rules.

If you're getting messages from your payment gateway, this probably means that your server is defaulting to use TLS 1.0 or 1.1 instead of the required TLS 1.2. Usually this is due to outdated software or configuration issues on your server. To fix this you or your host will probably need to update packages like `OpenSSL` and `curl`.

This PHP test script can be helpful in identifying the OpenSSL and curl versions that your server is using, whether or not it is capable of communicating over TLS 1.2. I might advise running it, and sharing the results with your web host.

https://gist.github.com/olivierbellone/9f93efe9bd68de33e9b3a3afbd3835cf

Also, helpful link about upgrading OpenSSL from Stripe
https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-upgrade-my-openssl-to-support-tls-1-2